# Market price of interest rate risk under the CIR model

Tags: interest-rate, optimization, price, stochastic-processes, calibration

My goal is to find the market price of risk associated with the interest rate under the CIR model whose stochastic differential equation under the physical measure is given:
\begin{eqnarray}\label{ref3}
dr^{\mathbb{P}}_t = \theta (\kappa - r_t)dt + \sigma \sqrt{r^{\mathbb{P}}_t}dW^{\mathbb{P}}_t, 
\end{eqnarray}
Applying the Girsanov´s theorem allows finding the dynamics of the CIR model under a risk-neutral measure, which is given by:
\begin{equation}\label{ref5}
dr_t^{\mathbb{Q}} = \theta^*(\kappa^* - r_t^{\mathbb{Q}})dt + \sigma \sqrt{r_t^{\mathbb{Q}}}dW_t^{\mathbb{Q}}
\end{equation}
with new transformed parameters $\theta^*$ and $m^*$, which are defined by
\begin{equation}\label{ref6}
\theta^* = \theta + \lambda, \; \kappa^* = \frac{\theta \kappa}{\theta + \lambda}
\end{equation}
where $\lambda$ is interpreted as the market price of risk. In order to find a value for $\lambda$, we first need to find the estimations of physical parameters by using historical data. Afterwards, we need to use zero-coupon bond prices to calibrate the model for $\lambda$.

My problem is how to use zero-coupon bond price to calibrate the model for $\lambda$ through estimated parameters from the previous stage. I can find the estimations for physical parameters, but I can not fully understand how to perform the last process in practice.